# Function in the script file not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my `script.js` I have this:

```
$(function () {
   function addColors(basicColors) {
      ...
   }
});
```

And in `HTML`:

```
<head>
<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   ...
<script>
   ...
   addColors(basicColors);
</script>
...
```

But in console i am getting

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addColors is not defined
```

The script file is correctly referenced as other functionality defined in that file is working just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a scope issue. `addColors` is defined as a local function *within* the anonymous function being passed to jQuery to execute when the page loads (in `$(function() { ... })`). Outside that function, `addColors` isn't defined.

If you want `addColors` to be global, you can define it before the `$(function() { ... })` in `script.js`.